# What hashing algorithm does express-session use for session id cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Title says it all, I am just interested in what algorithm is used to hash these cookies, and I need help, because i couldn't find out it myself by looking at the sources.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- It doesn't use a hashing algorithm. It uses `uid(24)` instead. `uid(n)` generates random, unpredicable, values:

  - `generateSessionId` is here: https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/2d54f0dca1506883bebc634fcb7135c2f02c47cd/index.js#L507
  - ...which calls `uid(24)`
  - ...which is in the `uid-safe` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uid-safe
  - ...which generates cryptographically safe random numbers. Session-identifiers must be unpredictable.
- Session identifiers (in any context, really) should not be based on a hash of anything anyway because:

  - Session content tends to be mutable, not immutable, so using a hash of a session's state or content would make it impossible to retrieve it after it's been changed.
  - If two users coincidentally have the same session-state content then they'd have the same session-id value, which isn’t what you want either.

Comment: Thanks, and what about "secret" key then? What is it used for?

Comment: @Nick what references to “secret” keys are you seeing and where?

Comment: well, a session cookie has Value, and as i imagine its same session ID as on the server but encrypted using "Secret" key that "app.use(session({
    secret: "some key",". Am I right?

Comment: the secret is used to sign the cookie to prove that the server created the cookie. It's unnecessary since the session id is unpredictable

Comment: @No_name Signing the cookie isn't unnecessary in all cases - but if sessions are machine-specific but the web-application is in a web-farm or cluster without shared-session state then that could be used to allow load-balancers to redirect the session to the correct host.